# HP ProLiant DL 180 G5 - Can't see disks

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-raid, hp-proliant

I'm currently learning how to manage the storage of a HP proliant dl 180 g5. It has a Smart Array P400 RAID controller which works fine. So I've actually the problem, that I can't see disks which are not in RAID context. HP's Array configuration utility can see all disk, but these not raided disks are not shown to the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The P400 is a array-management card, all disks have to be in one array or another in order to be visible to the BIOS, you can add them all to one array then create individual R0 logical disks if you want but they probably won't map directly to physical disks unless you spend a lot of time tweaking things. What is it you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: My plan is that I have a hardware raid for the os (Two 500gb sata with raid 1). For all other disk I want a software raid and on a higher level lvm. So I'm not depedent on the raid controller.

Comment: But you are, they're connected to the card, they have to be part of one array or another, they can't just be 'passed through'.

Comment: I understand. You suggested me to create Raid0 logical disks. What happens if the controller goes broken? Will i be able to read the disks? Thanks you for your kind help!

Comment: Okay, I made a raid0 with one disk. I then partitioned, formatted and copied some files on it. After I removed the disk, I have attached to my USB Satacontroller and could read everything.

Comment: Well if the controller breaks well you'll lose service until you replace it of course but the array configuration is stored on all disks so the new controller will just inherit the config of the old controller. Ok, read the stuff about what you did with the disk but I'm still totally confused what you're trying to do, can you explain, I might be able to help more.

Comment: @Wiegand - Outside of some very specific usage scenarios, you should always be utilizing RAID on server drives.

Comment: Here is my plan visualized: http://www.imagebanana.com/view/igmh4zqq/storageplan.png
I'm afraid that the data is lost due to a faulty raid controller. Therefore, the software raid. I hope that i can read the data without these one raidcontroller.

Comment: What? the data is lost due to a faulty raid controller? what makes you think this? why would software raid be better at this? I think you've got your wires crossed. Looking at your image you've got the raid 1 and raid 1+0 the wrong way around, either way you're better off using the hardware raid controller for the R10, via software your writes will be half the speed as if you used a hardware controller as you'll have to write the data twice.

Comment: @Weigand; you're running into so many "problems" because you're misunderstanding how the technology works. You might want to get someone involved who knows what they're doing.

Comment: Yes, I think so that a software raid would be better at this, because if the controller breaks, i'll have to replace with the same controller. A software raid is more portable. I can use the raid on any other machine, can't I? 
As I said, I'm learning. Please excuse my stupidity. :) Thanks for your answers!

Comment: But your server will be slower? You're not listening.

Comment: If you use the P400's RAID, and put the drives in any other computer with an HP Pxxx controller (must support SATA, so can't use SCSI controllers obviously) the array will stay in tack and be usable. The P400 does not store any configuration data on it; it keeps all that data on the drives themselves.

Comment: @Chopper3 Because the cpu has to manage the raid? Is there additional a lower writing speed to the sw-raided disk?

@Chris S Thanks for this information. I thought that it only works with this one controller and firmware.

Comment: Yes, see my comment above, all HP controllers are forward and backward compatible.

Comment: Thats nice. I've learnd a lot today. Thank you. I wish you a nice weekend :)